# How to get ModelAndView object coming from Spring into Vue data?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, thymeleaf, modelandview

I have one controller class:

```
@RestController
public class ItemController {

    @Autowired
    private ItemService itemService;


    @GetMapping("/auction_items")
    public ModelAndView getAllItems() {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
            List<Item> itemList = itemService.getAllItems();
            mv.addObject("auctionItems", itemList );
            mv.setViewName("auction_items");
            return mv;
        }
    }
```

and then I am trying to get in my getitems.html page as:

```
<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      auctionItems: <%= ${auctionItems} %>
    }
  })
</script>
```

I see that with Thymeleaf is works as th:object="auctionItems". How about Vue in this case?
Or How shall I mark thymeleaf object to vue data?

Any other suggestions would also be appreciated.
My main objective is to use Vue on the front end page.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, in `getitems.html` you inserted a `<script>` that contains this code `<%= ${auctionItems} %>` that should be executed.

This is wrong as the `<% %>` code is executed on server-side, in a servlet, then the result is returned to the user and you actually try to execute that on client side in a script tag. It can't possibly work.

If you want that the `auctionItems` reach the javascript, then you should add it as a data attribute to an html div and retrieve it from js. I'll sketch this down:

```
// in your html
<div id="dataDiv" data-auctions="#{auctionItems}"></div>

//in your js - of course, you can change it to use jQuery if you want
var auctions = document.getElementById("dataDiv").getAttribute('data-auctions');
```

This is not the best approach, but looks very close to what you tried to do.

A better approach would be to not store the auctionItems into the html itself and only make a GetRequest in js when you want the data from the backend, like so:

```
$.get('/auction_items', function (data, textStatus) {  
    alert('status: ' + textStatus + ', data:' + data);
});
```

And your controller should return a response containing the data, not storing it into the Model.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I saw in ruby on rails that you can directly assign the object coming from controller to Vue data variable:

`<script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        services: <%= services.to_json.html_safe %>,
        total_amount: 100,
        checkedServices: [],
        visits_services_attributes: <%= visit.visits_services.to_json.html_safe %>
      }
    })
</script>`

I want to assign vue data variables similarly and work on the current page. I don't want to keep another call to controller on the same page.

Comment: I am a bit confused and if you can point to where you got this from maybe it can help. What I wanted to show you is a better approach (that will definitely won't call the controller multiple times). I will point again the fact that `<% %>` can't be executed in `<script></script>` tags. Check your console log and you'll probably have a typo issue.

Comment: Hey Catalin, Thanks. I figured out.

Comment: @CatalinPirvu, why wouldn't `<% %>` be executed in script tags? they will be executed on the server side and result printed in the html source, and then be available for script ptocessing?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it.

```
data: {
      auctionItem: [(${auctionItem})],
      userBidValue: null
     }
```